# Inserting webpage (frontend) <li> to MySQL table

Tags: php, html, mysql

When a web page on my website loads, it creates a list of content in < li > format, I'm trying to save this list to MySQL database after page loaded. Each < li > should be treated as one record; and only text should be saved in database. Example of < li > is:

```
<?php $keywords = 
"<ul>
<li><a href="...">Keyword_1</a></li>
<li><a href="...">Keyword_2</a></li>
</ul>";
?>
```

My code is:

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'username';
$dbpass = 'password';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO wp_keywords (keyword) VALUES ($keywords)";

mysql_select_db('database');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Here:

> wp_keywords is a table
>
> keyword is a table field
>
> $keywords is a variable carrying the values

Error occurring is:

> Could not enter data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '

Comment: Please use prepared statements- your code is subject to SQL injection. Actually, please stop what you're doing and do some reading on the top web vulnerabilities before continuing.

Comment: I understand this concern, however first to fix the error occurring while inserting content to database.

Answer (score 0):

Well your code is at least wrong in 2 places. (If this is the code you are using and not just a part of it.)

Your sql query will result in the following:

```
INSERT INTO table (column_name) VALUES
```

I suspect column_name is not a column name. And ($keywords) is empty so there are no values to put into the table.

Comment: > wp_keywords is a table

> keyword is a table field

> $keywords is a variable carrying the values

Comment: My suggestion would be to echo the $sql variable to find out what query is actually being parsed to the database.